# Limitation of Solace VMR Trial Version

Tags: solace

May I know whether there is any limitations to Solace VMR trial version?  I exported CLI commands to setup a VPN from a Solace appliance.  I can run the CLI script to create a VPN on appliance but when I tried to run the same script in VMR, it seems to have issues.  Similarly, VMR does not seem to allow me to setup SSL.  Any advice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The following Solace appliance features are not currently supported by the Solace VMR:

- High-Availability (HA) router redundancy
- TLS/SSL client certificates
- TLS/SSL bridging
- TLS/SSL client connections with Solace Java and JMS messaging API versions less than 7.1.1.169
- Compressed traffic
- Eliding
- HA Config-Sync
- Upgrades and downgrades using the ‘boot’ command
- Legacy mode SEMP over msg-bus commands
- Legacy mode ACL rule enforcement
- SNMP
- Cut-through guaranteed messaging

This list of feature limitations and other known issues are available in the [Solace VMR Release Notes](http://sftp.solacesystems.com/download/VMR_EVAL_RN).

The Solace VMR has a lower capacity than the Solace hardware solution, therefore some of the limits on system resources differ. If you have a license for the Solace appliance, you will have access to the SolOS_system_limits_and_alerts_VMR.xlsx spreadsheet in your customer portal which documents all limits of the VMR.

Some examples include:

- Client connections - 1000 on VMR, 9000/200,000 on the appliance (depending on the model)
- Queues and topic endpoints - 1000 on VMR, 16000 on appliance
- Topic subscriptions - 500000 unique and 1000000 non-unique on VMR, 5000000 unique and 10000000 non-unique on appliance

**These feature and resource limitations are accurate for the 7.1.1.342 SolOS version of the VMR and appliance. These values may be different for other versions.**

Note that these limits apply for both the Evaluation and the Enterprise version of the Solace VMR. The limitation of the Evaluation version, as compared to the Enterprise version, is that it contains only a 30-day trial license and is not supported for production environments.

If your CLI script is returning errors, it could be that it is trying to enable a feature that isn't supported or it has exceeded a limit on the VMR.

Comment: Hello, my bad.  I forgot to setup SSL.  It is working fine after I setup SSL.  Thank you, anyway.

Comment: max-connections seems to be limited to 100 on community edition: solace(configure/message-vpn)# max-connections 10000
Max-connections 10000 exceeds that supported by this hardware (100)     and this is documented nowhere.